# Ionic 3 storage saves for one page but not for the next

Tags: ionic3, ionic-storage

I have created an Ionic 3 application that stores a string in Storage. I'm using the SQLlite plugin and I can see that string gets stored properly on a page because immediately after I .set the value, i do a .get and am able to verify that the key/value matches.

```
this.storage.set('token', 'testing')
        .then(() => {
          this.storage.get('token')
            .then((token) => {
              console.log(token); //I get 'testing' as I should
            })
        });
```

When I go to the next page in Ionic, I attempt to retrieve the key from storage but I get a null value.

On the next page I have the following code:

```
this.platform.ready()
.then(() => {
  this.storage.get('token')
  .catch(err => {
  })
  .then((token) => {
    console.log(token); //I get null here instead of 'testing'
  });
})
```

On my app.modules.ts file I have added `import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';` and `IonicStorageModule.forRoot()` under imports.

Comment: i agree with the answer. Use storage.ready() if you need to but generally use storage straight

Answer (score 1):

`this.platform.ready()` returns a Promise, so it resolves or rejects only once and I suspect you already visited this page before you `set('token'` , so page is added to the stack (when you visit page in Ionic it adds it to the stack so when you visit it again it doesn't need to initialise it again) and when you visit again, `this.platform.ready()` doesn't fire anymore. If you need to check for platform, you could:

`if (this.platform.is('cordova')) { }`

Comment: I agree with the answer; you could use `this.platform.ready()`  to check if the platform is ready in the `app.component.ts` file only once before redirecting the user to the first page of your app, and then just use the storage directly since the platform will be ready by that time.